# Difference between servlet API and servlet and JSP API?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been making JSP and Servlets in NetBeans without adding this servlet API or JSP API why do I need to add it in my project library folder, if the same is available in my local server Tomcat/Glassfish or in the Web server I upload the files to. Already Netbeans Servlets are working without adding these extra libraries right?

Answer (score 0):

You need them (at least the API jars) if you want to compile your code. Netbeans needs the interfaces, Tomcat/Glassfish need to provide implementations as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a NetBeans user, but I believe that NetBeans might automatically add the Servlet/JSP API libraries to the classpath for you, e.g. the GlassFish Library, so you don't have to do that.

If NetBeans don't do that, or if you have another IDE, then you have to add them to the classpath yourself, in order to compile any classes that relies on Servlet classes, e.g. `Servlet` or `Filter` subclasses.

Answer is based on the `GlashFish Server 3.1` entry under the `Libraries` node shown in step 5 on this help page: [Creating First Servlet Application using Netbeans IDE](http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/creating-servlet-in-netbeans.php):

[image]